# How are these tempdb tables automatically created after each SQL Server restart?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, tempdb

I have a session state management implementation using SQL Server. There is an ASPState database, and ASPStateTempApplications & ASPStateTempSessions tables in the *tempdb* database.

When I restart the SQL Service, *tempdb* database recreates, but these tables recreate too. I want to know: how do these tables recreate automatically each time?

I looked for start-up parameters and jobs, but did not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input. Actually, I found the answer:

Those tables were created by a stored procedure that is set to execute on startup of the database engine service, configured via [the `sp_procoption` system stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

They must have also been created in the `model` database. Anything in `model` gets created in any new database that's created (but not restored or attached), including `tempdb` on restart.